# How to find the position of an item in the vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

All i want to do to find the item in the vector and its position in the vector, so that i can perform operations(insert or delete) in the vector. I've tried std::binarysearch but it only tells if the element exist or not by using conditional statement.

```
if(binarysearch(arr.begin(),arr.end(),98)
{
   cout<<"98 exists in the vector";
}
else 
{
   cout<<"98 does not exist in the vector";
}
```

Does any other function exist in  that will return the position of the found item in the vector?

Comment: You are likely using [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) incorrectly. It returns an iterator with indicates the element's position.

Comment: `std::find` does give you position (iterator). If you have sorted vector use `std::lower_bound`

Comment: These operations are not O(1)

Comment: Insert and delete are not O(1) time for a vector.

Comment: Both `std::find` and `std::binarysearch` return an iterator. To convert an iterator into an index (position) use `std::distance`. But you want the iterator not the position.

Comment: "*so that i can perform operations(insert or delete) in the vector with constant time complexity*" as others have pointed out, you can't do this.

Comment: @MartinYork does `std::binarysearch` also returns an iterator?

Comment: @ShantanuDwivedi I mean [lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) which does a binary search (or more specifically if does log2(n) comparisons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

std::find and std::find_if both return an iterator. You can use this iterator to delete or insert and you can calculate the index of the item from this iterator:

```
std::vector<char> v = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

// Search for 'b'
auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 'b');

// To get the index of 'b'
auto index = it - v.begin();

// To insert in front of 'b' (the result is a vector of 'a', 'x', 'b', 'c')
// You cannot use the iterator after this operation!
v.insert(it, 'x');

// Search 'c' and delete it
it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 'c');
v.erase(it);
```

Iterators are only valid as long as the vector is not modified. So every insert(), push_back(), erase() or clear() invalidates all iterators.

In case of the std::vector, the iterator behaves like a plain pointer. You can move it around (++it, --it) and you can do math with it (i.e subtract one iterator from another to get the distance oder subtract the begin() iterator to get the absolute index).

If you insert into or delete from a vector some or all items have to be moved. (i.e. if you delete 'b' from {'a', 'b', 'c'}, 'c' has to be moved to the position of former 'b'). Thats the reason why iterators pointing to any item at or after the deleted item are invalidated as soon as the vector is modified.

If you add new elements to the vector the reserved capacity may be too small to hold the new value. In this case a new memory block is allocated and all existing items are copied from the old memory block to the new, bigger memory block. So inserting may invalidates all iterators even if you are just appending new values.

Comment: does `std::binarysearch` also return an iterator?

Comment: No it doesn't. But you can use std::lower_bound to implement a binary search as described in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

Comment: Well std::find is better as I will always not have sorted input.

Comment: Your iterator invalidation rules are too stringent.